# How to add an image to label using Javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net

Is it possible to assign `Image` to `label` text from `Javascript`

I tried this but I am not getting the `Image`

`document.getElementById("<%=Label1.ClientID%>").innerHTML = "<img src='Popup(Images)/information.png' />&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Hello";`

Comment: What browser are you using? Is the image path correct?

Comment: Use jQuery, that's the first, and second - can you post an HTML.

Comment: I tested in Mozila and Chrome didn't get the image.. Yeah image path is correct

Comment: I am using `Label` from `asp.net` controls

Comment: OOps sorry unfortunately i forgot to add the required image.. I am absolutely sorry :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is doable, but its not recommended.

see it working : http://jsfiddle.net/diode/BgBDT/5/

There is something wrong in your code. I mean id of the label or path of the image is wrong.